# Populating Class[] with JSON in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

As part of my model I have this class in TypeScript:

```
module App.Model {

    export class Unit {
            id: number;
            participantId: number;
            name: string;
            isProp: boolean;
        }
}
```

In the controller, I need a a hash with the `id` as key:

```
module App.Controllers {
    export class MyController {

        public units: App.Model.Unit[];

        populateDemoData() {
            this.units = {
                "1": { "id": 1, "participantId": 1, "name": "Testname", "isProp": true },
                "2": { "id": 2, "participantId": 1, "name": "Another name", "isProp": false }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

However, compiling the controller, I get the following error message:

```
Error 2 Cannot convert '{  }; [n: number]: App.Model.Unit; }' to ' }; [n: number]: App.Model.Unit; }' is missing property 'concat' from type 'App.Model.Unit[]'.
```

What am I doing wrong? And why is TypeScript asking for a `concat` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `units` as an Array object, but assigned it a literal object. Just to clarify, a hash (a literal object) is not an array.

If all the IDs are an integer you can still use the array but it would be like this instead:

```
populateDemoData() {
    this.units = [];
    this.units[1] = { "id": 1, "participantId": 1, "name": "Testname", "isProp": true };
    this.units[2] = { "id": 2, "participantId": 1, "name": "Another name", "isProp": false };
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Ok, you have to define a hash table to do that, but you also need to make `App.Model.Unit` an interface that matches your JSON objects.

```
module App.Model {

    export interface Unit {
        id: number;
        participantId: number;
        name: string;
        isProp: boolean;
    }

    export interface UnitHashTable {
        [id: string]: Unit;
    }
}

module App.Controllers {

    export class MyController {

        public units: App.Model.UnitHashTable;

        populateDemoData() {
            this.units = {
                "1": { "id": 1, "participantId": 1, "name": "Testname", "isProp": true },
                "2": { "id": 2, "participantId": 1, "name": "Another name", "isProp": false }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. How would I define the units as a hash? I meant hash! I was playing around with the definition, originally it was `units: App.Model.Unit[]` producing the same error. I update the question, sorry!

Comment: Looks great, thanks. I'll check later tonight when back online!